# Cmd.exe - what do these symbols mean in ftype command?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, path, file-extension, symbols

Just trying to understand something here.. In playing around with file extensions, type assoc .bat and get .bat=batfile, then ftype batfile and get "%1" %*. The same happens with ".exe". Whereas when I run ftype for word.document.12 I get the path for WINWORD.EXE.

My question is, what do the "%1" %* symbols mean from when I run ftype batfile? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are described in the help accessed via `ftype /?`.

Basically, the `%1` refers to the filename, while `%*` gets every argument passed to the file that has been executed. These are in the same format as [`cmd.exe`'s own parameter handling](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), as [used in batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php).

Text taken from `ftype /?`:

```
.................................................  Within an open
command string %0 or %1 are substituted with the file name being
launched through the assocation.  %* gets all the parameters and %2
gets the 1st parameter, %3 the second, etc.  %~n gets all the remaining
parameters starting with the nth parameter, where n may be between 2 and 9,
inclusive.  For example:

    ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
    FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*

would allow you to invoke a Perl script as follows:

    script.pl 1 2 3
```